# How to identify a user (Oracle) that is locked due to unsuccessful login attempts

Tags: oracle, security

How to differentiate in oracle a user deliberately locked by the security administrator and locked due to unsuccessful login attempts

Answer (score 6):

Select the user information from `dba_users` and look at the `ACCOUNT_STATUS`. If the status is `LOCKED` then the user was deliberately locked. If it is `LOCKED(TIMED)` then it is locked because of multiple wrong passwords. If you have set the `PASSWORD_LOCK_TIME` then the user will be unlocked after this time is reached.

```
select   username, account_status
from     dba_users
where    username='A-USERNAME'
/
```

Comment: Thanks. This was the case until some policy was recently modified by our DBA -set something to "default" (I am just an end user monitoring user access to our several systems). After this policy was implemented, either way the status is simply LOCKED. Should I ask the DBA to set the policy to whatever it was earlier?

Comment: The DBA sets the user profiles. You can ask him to either change (back) the profile. Perhaps he is not aware that it changed or he had some reason for the change. If you want more information about the user profiles then check the documentation or ask your DBA.